# LISTAGG for all rows and generate hash in one select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query. This query looks for records from a table and writes them to a string. But the problem for me is this script only works for one key ( where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' ) and not for all keys that are tables. I can't fix it.

```
select LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) as alldev
from ( select t.DEVNAME,   
              row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE) rn_asc     
       from ASU_DEVICES t
       where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
) t
```

But then I want it that will be in the "alldev" column, convert it to hash and write it in the column

```
SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(alldev)) md5_val
FROM DUAL;
```

And then I want to write this file to the "HASH" table, in column 'key', and the 'hash'.

```
insert into hesh(key,hesh) VALUES ( t.keys ,md5_val)
```

This is all I want to do with one request or two, but for all keys at the same time. I would appreciate your help.

I just can't merge three different queries into one.

Comment: Just curious, in your original attempt, what is the point of the subquery? You define RN_ASC by using analytic ROW_NUMBER, but then you don't use that anywhere. Why not simply say ORDER BY SEQUENCE in the LISTAGG function directly, if you must order the developer names by SEQUENCE? This is quite apart from how you would then take the result, hash it and use the output for INSERT or UPDATE to HESH table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all of them using the following for all the **KEYS**:

```
INSERT INTO HESH (KEY, HESH)
    SELECT
        KEYS,
        DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ALLDEV))
    FROM
        ( SELECT T.KEYS,
                 LISTAGG(T.DEVNAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY 1) AS ALLDEV
            FROM ASU_DEVICES T
        GROUP BY T.KEYS
        );
```

### Update

You can use merge to achieve to update in the ecisting record as follows:

```
MERGE INTO HESH H
USING ( SELECT T.KEYS,
                     LISTAGG(T.DEVNAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY 1) AS ALLDEV
                FROM ASU_DEVICES T
            GROUP BY T.KEYS
            ) SRC
ON (H.KEY = SRC.KEY)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET H.HESH = DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ALLDEV));
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this but not to write to the table
  new, and write to the existing hash column, and where the keys would be the same. I showed an example of my answer, thank you for your help)) and for understanding my problems)

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way but didn't make a table entry

```html
with txn as ( select keys, hesh  from (
select keys ,
       LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) as hesh
  from (
     select t.keys, t.DEVNAME,   
            row_number () over (partition by keys order by TO_NUMBER(SEQUENCE, '99')) rn_asc
            from ASU_DEVICES t
  ) t 
 group by keys  ))

SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(txn.hesh)) md5_val , txn.keys
          FROM txn;
```

As one solution to the problem, I think so, but it does not work

```html
UPDATE ASU_ROYTE SET hesh
SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(txn.hesh)) md5_val 
FROM txn
WHERE ASU_ROYTE.keys = txn.keys
```